# Is it possible to use multiple views or nested views in ngRoute angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

```
.when('/login', {
       templateUrl: '/Login/_Login.aspx',
       controller: 'LoginCtrl',
       caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
       resolve: {
           deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
               return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                   name: 'modelFile',
                   files: [
                       'http://localhost:59618/Content/Js/Login/Login.js',
                   ]
               }]);
           }]
       }
   })
```

Can i use multiple views or nested view here? i don't want to use stateprovider.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking you cannot use nested routes in ng-route, at least not like the way you can nest views in ui.router. However you can define your URLs in nested fashion. Then you can make use of $route and $routeParams to extract information from the routes.

**Config**

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/orders", { ... })
  .when("/orders/:id", { redirectTo: "/orders/:id/details }
  .when("/orders/:id/details, { ... });
```

**Controller**

```
var ctrl = function($scope, $route, $routeParams) {

  var parts = $routeParams.split('/');  //orders/1/details => ["order", 1, "details"]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank @Pratik.. not exactly what i need but yes first line was enough.